# Find the string subtract matching values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

[image]

I want to calculate J column cells automatically based on A , C and I cells, as shown in screenshot for contract ID 111 total value is 800 and in C column  there are total 600 values against 111 contract ID, I want to to auto calculate the remaining amount in J cells against each contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUMIFS` and simple subtraction.

```
=I2-SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,H2)
```